# Call a C++ project main() in Python in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, python

I have **a C++ project and a Python project under one solution in Visual Studio.** I am reluctant to modify the C++ project, because it is complicated and now complete. I don't want to touch on it any more. So to integrate them, I choose to call the C++ project in Python, instead of the other way round.

I wish to **pass the parameters from Python to**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

of **the C++ project.**

How may I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments of `main()` are the command-line arguments of the program. So if you do for example this in Python:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['myCppprogram.exe', 'foo', 'bar'], ...)
```

then the following will hold in `main()`:

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  assert(argc == 3);
  assert(argv[1] == std::string("foo");
  assert(argv[2] == std::string("bar");
}
```

Comment: But what is the 2nd argument ...? And how may I choose to run the Python script? After I press the green Local Window Debugger, the debugger goes to find the C++ main() and run it.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng What do you mean by "2nd argument?" `argv` is an array of C-style strings containing the individual command-line arguments, if you mean that.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng Which projects gets run when you press "Start Debugging" is controlled by the "StartUp project" settings. And in `Project > Properties > Debugging`, you can set the executable, arguments etc. Consult the VS help for details.

Comment: I mean the ... of Popen(). And I get name 'subprocess' is not defined error.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng That's a totally different question on using the Python module `subprocess`. If you're not familiar with that part of Python, read the documentation for that module.

Comment: you need to import the module 'subprocess' in Python by calling 'import subprocess' in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

According to what i have understood from your question, you want to call a .exe file from python and pass arguments to the C++ file.

```py
import subprocess

program = 'path to your exe file'  
argument = "0"

subprocess.call([program, argument])
```

This will execute the .exe from python  and the arguments passed can be read in C++ main as members of the array argv.